# click anywhere to close div inside and outside

Tags: javascript

This is a jscript to close the window when someone clicks anywhere outsite the Div to close.
my question is to make this window close when someone clicks on this by performing the action.

```
<div id="box"
style="height: 3em; position:absolute; top: 20%; left: 15%; border: 3px double">
<p>Click anywhere outside this box to close it.
</div>
<script>
document.onclick = function (e) {
e = e || event
var target = e.target || e.srcElement
var box = document.getElementById("box")
do {
      if (box == target) {
           // Click occured inside the box, do nothing.
           return
      }
      target = target.parentNode
 } while (target)
 // Click was outside the box, hide it.
 box.style.display = "none"
}
</script>
```

How to make a Div close when the click was occurred inside the DIV

Comment: Can you use Jquery? It will make your life easier...

Comment: Is this a practice or a business work ? It's really annoying to implements your requirement from scratch, considering those cross-browser issues, you should definitely get some JS library or framework involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML code itself,

```
<div id='box' style='height:10px; width:10px' onclick='CloseMe(this)'>...</div>
```

Implement the CloseMe function

```
function CloseMe( obj )
{

    obj.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: What if the text is anchor. when i tried them on anchor text it's not working.

Comment: you want to close the div by clicking on the 'X' text being displayed as an anchor?

Answer (score 0):

For the specific thing talking here, I didn't test it but I think change that loop to the following code could make it.

```
do {
    if (box != target) {
       // Click occured outside the box, do nothing.
       return
    }
    target = target.parentNode
 } while (target)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery you can use the `event.stopPropagation();` on the `click` function for you div

```
$(function(){
  $('html').click(function() {
    $('#box').hide();
  });

  $('#box').click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nCqwy/1/